# Including dynamically created sub-pages in JavaScript "isActive()"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Bootstrap implementation where the navigation bar is an unordered list with each items set to highlight when active. The highlight itself is styled using CSS but the check for active status is made using AngularJS:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}">
      <a onClick="pagetop()" href="#blog">BLOG</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The `isActive()` method is defined in an AngularJS Controller as:

```
function HeaderController($scope, $location){ 
    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
}
```

As you can see, AngularJS simply adds an `.active` class to the `<li>` item if the linked URL is active. This is the class that is styled using CSS. This works fine when the currently open page is *http://localhost:8888/a-s/#/blog/* but not when it's *http://localhost:8888/a-s/#/blog/sub-page/* or *http://localhost:8888/a-s/#/blog/sub-page/sub-sub-page/*. How can I modify the code to ensure all paths under */blog* trigger the `.active` class logic? Is there any way one could use wild-cards in this syntax?

Comment: share the method `isActive('/blog')`

Comment: Please see the update in the question...Sorry for missing it out the first time.

Comment: `return $location.path().indexOf(viewLocation) > -1;`

Comment: Great! Could you please repost this as an answer so I could accept it and close the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you checking whether path and the passed value are equal, instead you can check whether the passed value exists in the path

```
function HeaderController($scope, $location) {
  $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
    return $location.path().indexOf(viewLocation) > -1;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not clean solution. Because it work on http://localhost:8888/a-s/#/blog-another/ b or http://localhost:8888/a-s/#/blog_edit/ b and so on. It is need to update like this:

```
function HeaderController($scope, $location) {
  $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
    var path = $location.path();
    var addViewLocation = viewLocation+"/";
    var inPath = false;
    if(path.indexOf(addViewLocation)==-1)
    {
      inPath  = path.indexOf(viewLocation)+viewLocation.length==path.length;
    }
    else
      inPath = true;
    return inPath;
  };
}
```

This is test locations:

`isActive("www.location.ru/path","/path");
true
isActive("www.location.ru/path/tr","/path");
true
isActive("www.location.ru/path-r/tr","/path");
false
isActive("www.location.ru/path/","/path");
true
isActive("www.location.ru/path/we/ew","/path");
true
isActive("www.location.ru/path-another/we/ew","/path");
false`